# CPU Usage of a Process(task) Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, process, kernel, cpu-usage

How can I learn CPU usage percentage of a process in **kernel-space**?

We are trying to limit CPU usage of a process looking at a field added to **task_struct**.

For example if the field is 10 and the process has already consumed the %10 percent of total timeslice we need to prevent the process from running.

Answer (score -1):

Your can read the kernel CPU usage of a process from the proc file system (man proc):

> /proc/[number]/stat: Status
>   information about the process.  This
>   is used by ps(1).  It is defined in
>   /usr/src/linux/fs/proc/array.c.

[...]

> stime %lu: The number of jiffies that
>   this process has been scheduled in
>   kernel mode.

One jiffy is 1/100 second typically.